# Do something with part of array, then reinsert it back into array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating an array as such, splitting a string by every `-`:

```
$array = explode('-', $mystring);
```

I know I can then implode the array back into one string, eg:

```
$mystring = implode('-', $array);
```

But I first need to do something with the 3rd array element and reinsert it into the array before re-concatenating it. Here I am a bit stuck - I cant find any good resources showing this online.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply access the third element and reinsert it into the array before imploding

```
$string = "Foo-Bar-Foo2-Bar2";
$array = explode("-", $string);

$third = "Something else";

$array[2] = $third;
$string = implode("-", $array);

print($string);
```

Results

> Foo-Bar-Something else-Bar2

or you can even directly edit the entry

```
$array[2] = "Something else"
```